# Fazer uma condição para aplicar mascara em um EditText

Tags: android, edittext, mask

Não consigo fazer uma condição para aplicar mascara em um editText alguem me ajuda por favor ?

```
final EditText tel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        // Armazene seus TextWatcher para posterior uso
            //telMask = Mask.insert("(##)#########", tel);

        String digControle = String.valueOf(tel.getText().toString().charAt(4));
            //char numero = tel.getText().toString().charAt(4);
            if (digControle.equals(9)) {
                telMask = Mask.insert("(##)#####-####", tel);
            } else {
                telMask = Mask.insert("(##)####-####", tel);
            }

        tel.addTextChangedListener(telMask);
```

Comment: O que acontece? qual o erro?

Comment: diz que app parou de funcionar

Comment: Tem logger? Exibe algum erro?